# Google chart visualisation example does not work

Tags: javascript, html, json

In this offical google example I replaced the url getData.php by a valid internet url. The url works fine, when I use it in any browser address bar.
It delivers a valid json representation of a google DataTable Type.
When I use it in the script below, nothing happens. I only get an empty browser page.
What could be the problem?
My URL looks like:
https://alpenegg.hopto.org/LorawanBackend/lorawan/sensorservice/5
The server is expecting a GET Method.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you get any errors in your console? Probably the lib hasn't loaded when you execute your script.

Comment: No errors. I Even tried to debug it in Firefox.